# How to copy dynamically created file into testcontainer?

Tags: testcontainers

I have testcontainer defined as:

```
new OracleContainer("gvenzl/oracle-xe:21-slim-faststart")
            .withUsername(DEFAULT_DB_USER_NAME)
            .withPassword(DEFAULT_DB_USER_PASSWORD)
            .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource(
                            "testcontainers/oracle/initDbForLiquibase.sql", 0777),
                    "/container-entrypoint-initdb.d/init001.sql");
```

and it works fine. First line of that initscript has to be:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=XEPDB1;
```

let say, that I want two of these containers running at same time, then I need to specify `.withDatabaseName()`, and update the first line of that file to new name. If I want to reuse that whole file, I need to transform it's contents. I don't see any method which would accept input stream, and I'd like to avoid creating temp files, just to be able to create updated readable file somewhere on host machine.

What is the correct way how to do this?